# Linux: Background process linked to terminal window

Tags: linux, background-process

I am running linux and I am running a script/program in the background using

> *cmd &*

This works fine on Solaris, but on my Linux box (2.6.9-55/ Red Hat), the background process stops when the originating terminal window is closed/loses connection.
What do I need to change this, so that this works as it works on Solaris?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to use the disown command (it may be specific to bash, not sure about it).

Example:

```
cmd &
disown
```

should do the trick.

If you want to reattach later the job to the terminal, use:

```
disown -h
```

Alternatively, you can use screen. Use it this way:

```
screen
cmd
```

Then, to go back to the terminal, hit ctrl+a, then d.

To come back to the screen, type in any terminal:

```
screen -r
```

Comment: I think you're wrong about reattachment with `disown`.  Can you prove this performance?

Answer (score 7):

if you run nohup cmd &, so the program will ignore the SIGHUP it gets when the termial closes.

Comment: This is definitely the solution that works for me. All disown seems to do is remove the process from the jobs list.