# Running A command in linux via ssh2 that keeps running when session ends

Tags: linux, background-process

a simple question to one who knows...

I want to run a program in a Linux shell (ssh2)
I run the program with '&' so it should run on the background

But when I end the session , the program aborts.

How can I make the program run until finished and be able to fg it when I reconnect ?

Comment: Question is already answered here: http://serverfault.com/questions/41467/linux-background-process-linked-to-terminal-window

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Prefix the command with `nohup` to keep it from terminating.

To resume the program, run the program within a `screen` session.

- [nohup man page](http://linux.die.net/man/1/nohup)
- [screen Web site](http://www.gnu.org/software/screen/)